# Powershell XML Add Column

Tags: xml, powershell, addition

i've some truble while using Powershell and XML and don't get it :(

Maybe you can help me!

I have a XML Object like

```
[xml] $a = '<test><red>1</red><blue>2</blue></test>'
```

Now I want do add another Element to $a to get a solution like
    [xml] $solution = '123'

I tried it by generating a second xml object and appand it to the first one but it wont work. I look around in the internet but it wont work.

```
[xml] $a = '<test><red>1</red><blue>2</blue></test>'
[xml] $b = '<test><yellow>2</yellow></test>'
($a.test).appendchild($b.test,$true)
```

Do you have any idear for me?

Thanks a lot,
Best Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is an easier way but this works:

```
[xml] $a = '<test><red>1</red><blue>2</blue></test>'
[xml] $b = '<test><yellow>2</yellow></test>'
$b.test.ChildNodes | Foreach {
    $newElem = $a.CreateElement($_.Name, $_.NamespaceURI)
    $newElem.InnerXml = $_.InnerXml
    $a.test.AppendChild($newElem)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new node, append a text node to it, and then append it to your existing XML:

```
[xml]$a = '<test><red>1</red><blue>2</blue></test>'

$node = $a.CreateNode('element', 'yellow', '')
$text = $a.CreateTextNode(2)
$node.AppendChild($text)

$a.SelectSingleNode('/test').AppendChild($node)
```